# analyze range and if true tell me

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to see if the price of a stock has changed by 5% this week. I have data that captures the price everyday. I can get the rows from the last 7 days by doing the following:

```
select price from data where date(capture_timestamp)>date(current_timestamp)-7;
```

But then how do I analyze that and see if the price has increased or decreased 5%? Is it possible to do all this with one sql statement? I would like to be able to then insert any results of it into a new table but I just want to focus on it printing out in the shell first.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to compare today's value with last week's value, ignoring anything in between?

Comment: @AlejoBrz - Yes ignoring everything in between is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd to have only one stock in a table called data.  What you need to do is bring the two rows together for last week's and today's values, as in the following query:

```
select d.price
from data d cross join
     data dprev
where cast(d.capture_timestamp as date = date(current_timestamp) and
      cast(dprev.capture_timestamp as date) )= cast(current_timestamp as date)-7 and
      d.price > dprev.price * 1.05
```

If the data table contains the stock ticker, the cross join would be an equijoin.

Comment: +1 but you are missing the decrease option and are missing the closing ')' of your first cast

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff - I have multiple stocks in the same table. The table has data of ticker, price, yield, etc...I agree data is a poor choice for a table name. I'm unfamiliar with a "cross join" and "cast" as well so I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use query from the following subquery for whatever calculations you want to do. This is assuming one record per day. The 7 preceding rows is literal.

```
SELECT ticker, price, capture_ts
      ,MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY capture_ts ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS min_prev_7_records
      ,MAX(price) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY capture_ts ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS max_prev_7_records
  FROM data
```